# Solve in positive integers $n!=m^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

Is anybody know a solution of this problem?

(Sorry, correct question is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39210/solve-in-positive-integers-n-mm1).)

Comment: m=1, n=0 or 1. For larger n, there is a prime between n/2 and n, which guarantees an unsquared prime factor in the factorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bertrand's postulate (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: Not the first time ... I added the Wikipedia reference and thought twice, so was 18 seconds behind Robin.

Comment: Sorry Charles! It's an old chestnut though :-)

Answer (score 9):

From [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) it follows swiftly that there
are no solutions with $n>1$.

Comment: Just to be more detailed for those who may need it: If $p$ be is the largest prime less than $n$ then $p$ divides $n!$, hence $p$ divides $m^2$ so $p^2$ divides $n!$. So $n>=2p$ which contradicts Bertrand's postulate (and the only solutions are the trivial ones).