# does n!m! = t! have infinitely many solutions? besides trivial ones

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does n!m!=t! have infinitely many solutions in positive interger besides trivial ones? (n=0 m=1 etc)

Can't work this one out. thanks.

Comment: $(n!)!=(n!-1)!\cdot n!$ - is it trivial or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is considered trivial or not but $n! = (n!)!/(n!-1)!$. Let $n < m$, since $n! = t!/m!$ the range $(m,t]$ must avoid primes because if there was a prime in there $n!$ wouldn't contain it.

Comment: Thanks Nurdin. That counter example is sufficient for my needs.

Muad's point is interesting.

Comment: Also - there is related question - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39210/solve-in-positive-integers-nmm1
Because, if there are any $(m,n)$, such that $n!=m(m+1)$, then we have:$(m+1)!=(m-1)!\cdot n!$

Comment: @Nurdin Takenov: Could you please undelete your answer, so we can consider this question resolved?

Comment: Done. I just thought that it's too short to be an answer.

Comment: The OEIS sequence http://oeis.org/classic/A003135 is related to this question.

Comment: Wow, it gives really non-trivial example $10!=6!\cdot 7!$

Comment: I'm not at work but IIRC Sloane's book on unsolved problems in number theory mentions this question explicitly as being open, and mentions the parametric family spotted by many people in this thread, and also mentions 10!=6!7! as being an interesting solution, and, I think, asks if there are any more of this nature. I think this problem is hopelessly open. If I were at work I'd dig out the precise reference but I think you're not going to get anything concrete here unless there have been recent breakthroughs.

Comment: Kevin, are you thinking of Guy's book, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory? The reference is problem B23. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$(n!)!=(n!-1)!\cdot n!$ - is it trivial or not?

Comment: In the 1975 Erdos paper mentioned in OEIS sequence A003135, this is considered a trivial solution. See pages 27-28 of that paper.